# canLoad in children routes using NgRx

Tags: angular, angular-routing, ngrx, ngrx-store, angular-canload

I'm working in an Angular 9 app and I'm trying to load (or not) an specific module only when my app state (ngrx) have a property != null

First, I have an AuthGuard in my routes but with canActivate.
So I want the 'dashboard' module only loads when mt AppState have a token

Here is my route file

```
const routes: Routes = [
{
  path: '',
  component: AppLayoutComponent,
  canActivate: [ AuthGuard ],
  children: [
    { path: '',  loadChildren: () => import('./pages/modules/dashboard/dashboard.module').then(m => m.DashboardModule) }
  ]
},
{
  path: '',
  component: AuthLayoutComponent,
  children: [
    { path: 'session',  loadChildren: () => import('./pages/modules/session/session.module').then(m => m.SessionModule) }
  ]
},
{
  path: '**',
  redirectTo: 'session/not-found'
}];
```

And this is my AuthGuard. It localestorage doesn't have a session, then redirects to the login page.

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private router: Router, public authService: AuthService) {}


  public canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
    if (localStorage.getItem('session')) {
        // logged in so return true
        return true;
    }

    // not logged in so redirect to login page with the return url
    this.router.navigate(['session/signin']);
    return false;
  }
}
```

this is kind of what I want to do whit the canLoad in AuthModuleGuard, but this doesn't work

```
  public canLoad(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.store.select('session').pipe(
      take(1),
      map((authstate) => {
          console.log('Token status', authstate.token);
          if (authstate.token !== null) {
              return true;
          } else {
              this.router.navigate(['session/signin']);
              return false;
          }
        })
      );
  }
```

if I do this...  the application gives me errors and still loads both files

```
{
  path: '',
  component: AppLayoutComponent,
  canLoad: [ AuthModuleGuard ],
  children: [ ... ]
}
```

[image]

and If I do this ... the app never finish loading

```
{ path: '', canLoad: [ AuthModuleGuard ], loadChildren: () => import('./pages/modules/dashboard/dashboard.module').then(m => m.DashboardModule) },
```

HERE IS A STACKBLITZ EXAMPLE (including my folder structure)---> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-nasx7r

I need a way to load the dashboard module (and other modules) only if the token in my store are seted, and If is not, redirect to the Login. Please help

Comment: Either `canLoad` must be a property of the route containing `loadChildren` or it can be in a parent route and you can use `canLoadChildren`.

Comment: @AluanHaddad thank you for answer. Unfortunately I think the canLoadChildren doesn't exist inside the @angular/router tools

Comment: You're right. I am silly.

Comment: `canLoad` looks fine. The problem might be somewhere else, could you create a StackBlitz demo?

Comment: @AndreiGătej I just update the question with a stackblitz example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-nasx7r

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After spending some time on this, I've learnt some very interesting things:

- if you have both `loadChildren` and `children` in your route configuration, [the latter will be chosen](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/router/src/apply_redirects.ts#L292-L297)

```js
if (route.children) {
  // The children belong to the same module
  return of(new LoadedRouterConfig(route.children, ngModule));
}

  if (route.loadChildren) { /* ... */ }
```

This also denotes that `canLoad` is redundant in this case:

```js
{
  path: '',
  component: AppLayoutComponent,
  canLoad: [ AuthModuleGuard ],
  children: [ ... ]
}
```

as this route guard has effect when used together with `loadChildren`.

- you should be mindful of when to redirect from your guard

  With a configuration like this:

```js
{
  path: '',
  component: AppLayoutComponent,
  children: [
    { 
      path: '', 
      loadChildren: () => import('./pages/modules/dashboard/dashboard.module').then(m => m.DashboardModule),
      canLoad: [AuthModuleGuard]
    }
  ]
},
```

and a `canLoad` guard like this:

```js
canLoad(route: Route, segments: UrlSegment[]): Observable<boolean> {
  return this.store.select('session').pipe(
      take(1),
      map((authstate) => {
          console.log('Token status', authstate.token);
          if (authstate.token !== null) {
              return true;
          } else {
              this.router.navigate(['session/signin']);
              return false;
          }
      })
  );
}
```

you'll get into an infinite loop. When the app first loads, it will go through each configuration in a **depth-first** manner and will compare the **path** with the current segments(initially, `segments = []`).

But remember that if a route has a `children` property, it will go through each of them and see if the **segments match the route**. Since the child route has `path: ''`, it will match **any segments** and because it has `loadChildren`, it will invoke the `canLoad` guards.

Eventually, this lines will be reached:

```js
this.router.navigate(['session/signin']);
return false;
```

`this.router.navigate(['session/signin']);` indicates a redirect, which means it will repeat the steps delineated above.

---

The solution I came up with is to add a `pathMatch: 'full'` to your child route:

```js
{
  path: '',
  component: AppLayoutComponent,
  children: [
    { 
      path: '', 
      pathMatch: 'full',
      loadChildren: () => import('./pages/modules/dashboard/dashboard.module').then(m => m.DashboardModule),
      canLoad: [AuthModuleGuard]
    }
  ]
},
```

When the app loads, the **segments** will be an **empty array** and because `path: ''` matches any group of segments and that group of segments is `[]` initially, [there will be a match](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/router/src/apply_redirects.ts#L447-L453):

```js
if (route.path === '') {
  if ((route.pathMatch === 'full') && (segmentGroup.hasChildren() || segments.length > 0)) {
    return {matched: false, consumedSegments: [], lastChild: 0, positionalParamSegments: {}};
  }

  return {matched: true, consumedSegments: [], lastChild: 0, positionalParamSegments: {}};
}
```

This means that the guard will be invoked and the `if`'s alternative block will be reached and `this.router.navigate(['session/signin'])` will be invoked.

Next time the comparison is made, the segments will be (roughly) `['session', 'signin']` and there will be no match, since this is returned:

```js
{matched: false, consumedSegments: [], lastChild: 0, positionalParamSegments: {}}
```

If no match occurs, it will keep on searching until something is found, but the guard will not be invoked again.

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jiztph?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp-routing.module.ts)